# Regex with double asterisk javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need two regular expressions, one to get ** at the beginning of a string, and one at the end.

For example:

```
This is a **text** test
```

With an expression obtain the ** of the beginning and with another those of the end. There may be many more repetitions.

I have tried the following:

```
(\*\*)
^(\*\*)
/\*\*/
^/\*\*/
```

Thanks a lot

```
This **would** be a good **text** to do some **testing**
```

It should mark all the words that contain ** at the beginning.
And with the other you should mark all the ones that end with **

Comment: What if input is `Th**is is a **text** test`, which `**` do you want to match?

Comment: There would be two expressions. One to get all the ** from the beginning, and with another to get the ones from the end. For example the ** that contain a space before.
I do not know if I have explained myself very well

Comment: Not sure why you need a regex.  `.indexOf('**')` and `.lastIndexOf('**')` should do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match `**` just before a word use:

```bash
\B\*\*\b
```

- `\B` - is inverse of `\b`. It matches where `\b` doesn't
- `\b` - asserts position at a word boundary i.e. `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/C8oFpU/1)

And to match `**` just after a word use:

```bash
\b\*\*\B
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/C8oFpU/2)

Comment: It works perfect. But I only get one result, there may be one or many to select from. In my test text I have used several words with **

Comment: Can you edit your question with longer text and tell which `**` are not matched?

Comment: @JavierMuñozSánchez: Check this demo: https://regex101.com/r/C8oFpU/3 it matches 3 `**`s before words. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Yes, now it is working. Let me check it in my code. Thank you very much

Comment: Very elegant with the word boundaries :-)

Answer (score 1):

if I understand correctly:

- (\*\*)(?=[^\s]*\*\*)    -> obtain the ** at the beginning of the word
- (?<=[^\s])(\*\*)    -> obtain the ** at the end of the word

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. What page have you tried them on? In the first regex I get an error, in the second it only selects the last one. There may be more than one.

Comment: Sorry I just edited (the formatting changed my regex)

Comment: Now it works, but it selects all the text for me. I just need to get the ** at the start of a string. And with the second the ** at the end. The idea is to replace the data obtained from a json at the beginning with <b> and at the end with </b>

Comment: Please can you check again, I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

\*\*\w and \w\*\* (works in editpadlite at least)
or
\*\*(?=[a-zA-Z$\r]) and (?<=[a-zA-Z\r^])(\*\*)